# Modern Wafare 3 Spec Ops Split Screen Difficulties

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I was playing spec ops split screen with my house mate, I played on Veteran and he played on regular. He was on level one and I was on 36. When we were about to start the mission a pop-up message would say his progress would not be saved because he hasnt reach the specific level to unlock this spec op. Anyway we continued and once we completed the mission I was awarded 1 star when I expected three!?! and he was awarded no stars.

Was I awarded one star because he played on regular or because he had not unlocked that specific mission yet? Does the awarding of stars correspond to lowest difficulty setting selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you play on Veteran but your partner plays on Regular, the game will give you credit for the lower difficulty.  This applies to any situation where the difficulties chosen do not match.  Usually there is a warning to this effect, I believe over the picture of the SpecOp you're starting.